# Extract multiple page web table into Excel

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I have a table that spans across many pages. I'm able to pull the info from a designated page and pull it into a CSV table. My goal now is to have this iterate through all the pages and add it to the bottom of the previous page's info. Here is the code so far that works on a single page:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.mineralanswers.com/oklahoma/producers?page=1'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)

df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

The page URL is setup in the "...producers?page=1, ...producers?page=2 ...producers?page=3" format so I feel like it's likely possible using a loop, I just am having trouble amending the data instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is corrected example code to fetch 3 pages and append them to one DataFrame. You may [run this code here online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63985755#main.py).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for page in range(1, 4):
    url = 'https://www.mineralanswers.com/oklahoma/producers?page=' + str(page)
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df = df.append(df_list[-1], ignore_index = True)

df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```